# Arranging batch like a web page

Tags: windows, batch-file, html, user-input

Is it possible to arrange a batch file in such a way that when you type something into it, it will "re-size" its texts formats to show everything on the page? I know this sounds strange and is probably confusing you so let me put it this way for anyone that didnt understand. Imagine a cube of Jell-O. Now put a paperclip inside of it. You can still see the entire cube of Jell-O as well as what you have inserted into it. Here's a simple example of what I mean in code but it wont work.

Error: When I type into the "webpage" the lines on the far right go off and are repeated on the left at the next line, thus re-arranging everything on the page.

```
@echo off
cls
echo #######################################################################
echo ***@@*@@*@@*@@@*@@*@@@*@@*@@ Home @@*@@@*@@*@@*@*@@@*@@*@*@*@@*@@*@@*@@
echo ***********************************************************************
echo ##*Fan##*##*##*##*##*Downloads##*##*##*##*##*News##*##*##*##Updates##*#
echo #                                                                     #
echo #                                                                     #
set /p m=#Your Message Here:                                               #
echo #                                                                     #
echo #######################################################################
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: why do you want to do so ? to make your batch output nicer ?

Comment: Have a look into HTA instead of batches : see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692768.aspx - that will allow you to present a GUI to your users that is as fancy as you like!

Answer (score 1):

You can only set the properties of the CMD window to more columns and lines, and the window size will change.

Comment: Could you please give an example of this and explain how to use it? @foxdrive

Comment: Right click the title bar of the cmd window and select properties.  See how you go with the settings.